# Regex to extract three characters from string python

Tags: python, regex

I have a string as such `testing_7_3_4_testing`

i want to replace `testing_7_3_4_testing` with `testing_7.3.4_testing`, i have tried using `str.replace(/\d_\d/, ".")` and im getting some really weird results. Regex experts please help!

Comment: Maybe the results are weird because you are using JS code in Python?

Comment: i also tried this re.findall(r'[\d_\d]', str) to but it only matches first set "7_3" and not "7_3_4"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
import re

my_strs = [
    'testing_7_3_4_testing',
    'testing_7_3_testing',
    'testing_7_3_4_5',
    'testing_71_312_4123_testing',
]

pattern = r"""
    (\d+)      #Match a digit, one or more times, captured in group 1, followed by...
    _          #an underscore, followed by...
    (?=\d+)    #a digit, one or more times, but do not include as part of the match
"""

for my_str in my_strs:
    new_str = re.sub(pattern, r'\1.', my_str, flags=re.X)
    print(new_str)

--output:--
testing_7.3.4_testing
testing_7.3_testing
testing_7.3.4.5
testing_71.312.4123_testing
```

The pattern `(?=\d+)` says to match a digit, one or more times, but do not actually include the matching digits as part of the match.

Comment: this one is much more clever solution

Comment: Could you explain the pattern please?

Comment: @RafaelGutierrez, I added some comments to the pattern.  The tricky part is `(?=...)`, which is called a `lookahead`.  It matches something further ahead in the string--but does not include that part of the match in the actual match.

Comment: This answer is only good when you do not care about any custom boundaries (well, same as the other answer). If you need to replace `_` only between numbers in a string right after `testing_`, you'd better use a `testing(?:_\d+)+` regex and then replace each `_` within a lambda expression.

Answer (score 2):

Save each digit into it's own [saving group](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#grouping), reference the groups in your replacement string:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "testing_7_3_4_testing"
>>> re.sub(r"(\d)_(\d)_(\d)", r"\1.\2.\3", s)
'testing_7.3.4_testing'
```

Or, we can make use of a *replacement function*, which, in contrast to the first approach, also handles variable number of digits in the input string:

```
>>> def replacement(m):
...     x, y, z = m.groups()
...     return x + y.replace("_", ".") + z
... 
>>> re.sub(r"(.*?_)([0-9_]+)(_.*?)", replacement, s)
'testing_7.3.4_testing'
```

---

A non-regex approach would involve splitting by `_`, slicing and joining:

```
>>> l = s.split("_")
>>> l[0] + "_" + ".".join(l[1:-1]) + "_" + l[-1]
'testing_7.3.4_testing'
```

Comment: What if there are more than 3 numbers?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this particular pattern does not scale much, good point, but the digits look like a part of a version, let's see if this is good enough for the OP. Thanks.

Comment: what about a variable number of separated underscored numbers? i.e testing_7_3_4_testing or testing_3_4_testing etc...

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew okay, updated with a more scalable option.

Comment: @RafaelGutierrez the second option should cover variable numbers in the input string. Thanks.

Comment: how could i avoid putting periods between characters. For instance this wouldnt work for a string like such: tes_t_ing_3_4_testing

Comment: @RafaelGutierrez there is one more option in the answer (the replacement function) - might fit here, do check.

Comment: Thanks a bunch @alecxe